# Trouble connecting to wifi in Windows 7 VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows

I run Ubuntu 12.10 as host and I am trying to use VirtualBox for gaming with a Windows 7 guest. I cannot, however, connect to my wireless internet in the guest. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this works for my Windows XP VM

[image: Adapter 1 enabled, Attached to: Bridged Adapter, Name: wlan0]

It SHOULD work. Although I think in Vista they removed the PCnet support. Basically you usually have to monkey around with the different network settings options. I found [this article on VirtualBox network settings](http://www.sysprobs.com/virtualbox-network-host-windows-7).